# CSS3 Animation on HTML5 Progress Bars doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**HTML**

```
<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

**CSS**

```
progress[value]
{
    /* Reset the default appearence */
    -moz-appearance: none;
         appearance: none;

    /* Get rid of default border in Firefox and Opera. */
    border: none;

    /* Dimensions */
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;  
}

progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar 
{ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 135deg, 
                                            transparent 33%, 
                                            rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 33%, 
                                            rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 66%, 
                                            transparent 66% ),
                      -moz-linear-gradient( top, 
                                            rgba(255, 255, 255, .25), 
                                            rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) ),
                      -moz-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #f44 );

   border-radius: 2px; 
   background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;

   -moz-animation: animate-stripes 5s linear infinite;
        animation: animate-stripes 5s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes animate-stripes { 100% { background-position: 100px 0px; } }
     @keyframes animate-stripes { 100% { background-position: 100px 0px; } }
```

**DEMO** (Open this link in Firefox only)

http://jsfiddle.net/pankajparashar/CQGQ9/

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to animate the background stripes using css3 keyframes in firefox by changing the background position. However, this isn't working in firefox. The code above is a reduced test case written only for firefox.

Comment: Did you wrote that or you just picked that up from somewhere?

Comment: What's wrong with this piece of code? A question usually has a question mark somewhere in it.

Comment: You should've removed the comments too [here you go](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2012/01/03/cross-browser-html5-progress-bars-in-depth/) you should always attribute the original source, respect the real person behind this :)

Comment: I have updated the question with the problem I am currently facing. I thought the title itself is a question, and hence didn't mention it earlier..

Comment: I have also tried this and it appears that animations don't work on progress bars in Firefox. :/